# pushing JSON document in subdocument inserts only ObjectId

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, push

I've created a Model in Mongoose:

```
var userWalletSchema = new Schema({
   userid: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
   Transactions: [{
         Datum: {Type: Date},
         CODE: {Type: String},
         aantal: {Type: Number},
         soortTransactie: {Type: String}, 
         bedrag: {Type:Number}
   }]
},
{collection:'userWallet'});
```

I insert the following document:

```
var newRecord = { Datum: '2017-12-21T00:00:00+01:00',
CODE: 'IE00B3VWN518',
aantal: 48,
soortTransactie: 'Aankoop',
bedrag: 478 };
```

With this code:

```
UserWallet.findOneAndUpdate(
   { userid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)},
   { $push: {Transactions: newRecord}},
   { upsert: false },
   function (err, model) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(model);
   });
```

I've tried several permutations and options, but all give the same result: a record is pushed to the Transactions array, but it always contains the value _id: ObjectId('5a490c3376dfb6630464f6e1') (Id changes of course), but never the document I intended to insert.

What goes wrong here? I'd expect that inserting a new subdocument would be easy.

*Solution: I've found the problem. I typed "Type" with a capital T and the word should be all lowercase in JavaScript. So silly, took me 2 days to discover it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try another approach. First find the object, add the new Transaction to the object, and save it.

```
UserWallet.findOneAndUpdate({ userid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)}, function(err, userWallet) {
    userWallet.Transactions.push(newRecord);
    userWallet.save();
});
```

Comment: This is a more plain old Javascript approach is it? Nothing wrong with that, I'll give it a try and see if this works for me!

Comment: Not old JavaScript, I think it is a more Mongoose approach. You couldn't do this with the offial MongoDB client.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. The original code works but the schema definition contained an error: Type with capital T.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach in terms of saving is okay. If you check your schema, what you are saving is an ObjectId and not necessarily an actual object.

If you want to save objects of type User instead, then you can put the actual User Model in your UserWallet scheme declaration.

However, the approach I would recommend for your situation is to keep things just the way they are and use **population** when retrieving userWallets.

Example:

```
UserWallet.find().populate('user_id').exec(function(err,userWallets){

});
```

Now the user_id field of UserWallet will have the actual user object that is being referenced with the ObjectId. You can read more about population in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Thanks Asyene, thanks for your help. I've not tried populate yet. I guess I have to put the userid field in find() and the document in populate in your example? I'm searching the document with a specific userid and want to  a new document to the array in this case.

Comment: Yes, you should put the user_id that you are looking for in the find function as a key-value pair. And then also populate the user_id field of your results. That way, you can do UserWallet.user_id.username, UserWallet.user_id.id, UserWallet.user_id.email, etc..

Comment: Thanks, I found it. The original code works but the schema definition contained an error: Type with capital T.